# Convert Point Database to Body Shape

Tags: python, 3d

I have a database containing body scan results in point format.
For example :

```
point1=(x,y,z)
point2=(x2,y2,z2)
...
```

I want to convert these points to body shape.
And I want to do some processing on this points for example calculate neck diameter and some related calculation.
Any suggestion ? (module , tutorial etc...)

Answer (score 1):

You need some basic textbook on computational geometry. See this question, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308266/computational-geometry